# VBA Sorting multible rows

Tags: vba, excel

```
DoEvents

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:H" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("H3:H" & lastrow), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

I want to sort my table by the dates in row H, but it give me the error messages "Run-time error '1004': Sort method of Range class failed" and it points to the last row of code. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's working fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` to `lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row`